# Trouble building Jbuilder nested array

Tags: ruby, jbuilder

I am trying to write e ruby script that query an elasticsearch database and build a report on it. I am using jbuilder to build the query string like this:

```
require 'elasticsearch'
require 'date'
require 'jbuilder'

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true, host: 'x.x.x.x',  request_timeout: 10

filter_conditions = {}
filter_conditions['must'] = []
filter_conditions['should'] = []

filter_conditions['must'] << Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.term do
    json._type 'httpry-log'
  end
end

filter_conditions['must'] << Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.range do
    json.set! '@timestamp' do
      _now = DateTime.now
      json.gte (_now - 1.00/24).strftime('%Q').to_i
      json.lte _now.strftime('%Q').to_i
      json.format 'epoch_millis'
    end
  end
end

query = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.size 10
  json.query do
    json.bool do
      json.must do
        json.array!(filter_conditions['must'])
      end
    end
  end
end

puts query
```

But here is the result I get for the query:
**{"size":10,"query":{"bool":{"must":["{\"term\":{\"_type\":\"httpry-log\"}}","{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":1477919154057,\"lte\":1477922754057,\"format\":\"epoch_millis\"}}}"]}}}**

How to get the unscaped version of the inner array inside the main json output?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the query returns the same object and key each time:

```
a = your_query_hash
# The following map! will parse your string array into an array in ruby
a[:query][:bool][:must].map! { |arr| JSON.parse(arr) }
```

If the query does not return the same object and key each time, I'd suggest writing a recursive method that parses each value.